# Dictionary for multiple substrings with wildcard to single text values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, wildcard

```
I have a dictionary that maps many different values to specific codes.  I have to keep repeating code names that are very similar, when I think a wildcard of sometype would be more efficient.  Is this possible?

column_dict = {'subs_reversal_abc385': 'SUBS', 'subs_reversal_def385': 'SUBS', 'subs_reversal_ghi385': 'SUBS', 'entity reclass_abc385': 'MANU', 'entity reclass_def385': 'MANU', 'entity reclass_ghi385': 'MANU'}
```

What I'd like to do, to make the code less verbose, is something like this:

```
column_dict = {'subs_reversal*': 'SUBS', 'entity reclass*': 'MANU'}
```

[image]

Thank you for your help!

I'm not sure of a way to paste the Excel file as text without it coming out as one big glob or unformatted characters.  I'm trying to use this new dictionary to map the column_name and output the code columnn as a new column.

```
col_dict = {'pur_act': 'ACQ1', '_depr': 'DEPR', 'future_dated': 'FDIO', 'cap cost': 'MANU', 'reclass_': 'MANU', 'funded': 'MANU', 'manual': 'MANU', 'non-tax': 'MANU', 'other_': 'MANU', 'precomm': 'MANU', '_int': 'OINT',
'_additions': 'OPAA', '_pmt': 'OPMT', '_fx': 'OTFX', 'sub': 'SUBS', 'tia_': 'TIOP', 'unpaid': 'UNIO'}
```

```
column_name substring to search for code
forecasted_rou_asset_additions  _additions  OPAA
forecasted_rou_liability_additions  _additions  OPAA
commenced_leases_fcst_depr  _depr   DEPR
forecasted_additions_fcst_depr  _depr   DEPR
yoy_fx  _fx OTFX
commenced_leases_fcst_int   _int    OINT
forecasted_leases_fcst_int  _int    OINT
commenced_leases_fcst_pmt   _pmt    OPMT
forecasted_leases_fcst_pmt  _pmt    OPMT
tax amort cap cost_abc385   cap cost    MANU
tax amort cap cost_abc385   cap cost    MANU
funded const commit_abc385  funded  MANU
funded const commit_abc385  funded  MANU
future_dated_invoices   future_dated    FDIO
manual_adjustment_fcst_abc385   manual  MANU
manual_adjustment_fcst_abc385   manual  MANU
non-tax amort cap cost_abc385   non-tax MANU
```

```
df['code'] = df['column_name'].map(col_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple dictionary without the suffix, e.g.:

```py
column_dict = {"subs_reversal": "SUBS", "entity reclass": "MANU"}
```

and then use `str.rsplit` to test the key:

```py
k = "subs_reversal_abc385"
print(column_dict[k.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0]])
```

Prints:

```
SUBS
```

---

EDIT: IIUC, you can try:

```py
col_dict = {
    "pur_act": "ACQ1",
    "_depr": "DEPR",
    "future_dated": "FDIO",
    "cap cost": "MANU",
    "reclass_": "MANU",
    "funded": "MANU",
    "manual": "MANU",
    "non-tax": "MANU",
    "other_": "MANU",
    "precomm": "MANU",
    "_int": "OINT",
    "_additions": "OPAA",
    "_pmt": "OPMT",
    "_fx": "OTFX",
    "sub": "SUBS",
    "tia_": "TIOP",
    "unpaid": "UNIO",
}

df["code2"] = df["column_name"].apply(
    lambda x: next((v for k, v in col_dict.items() if k in x), None)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                           column_name substring to search for  code code2
0       forecasted_rou_asset_additions              _additions  OPAA  OPAA
1   forecasted_rou_liability_additions              _additions  OPAA  OPAA
2           commenced_leases_fcst_depr                   _depr  DEPR  DEPR
3       forecasted_additions_fcst_depr                   _depr  DEPR  DEPR
4                               yoy_fx                     _fx  OTFX  OTFX
5            commenced_leases_fcst_int                    _int  OINT  OINT
6           forecasted_leases_fcst_int                    _int  OINT  OINT
7            commenced_leases_fcst_pmt                    _pmt  OPMT  OPMT
8           forecasted_leases_fcst_pmt                    _pmt  OPMT  OPMT
9            tax amort cap cost_abc385                cap cost  MANU  MANU
10           tax amort cap cost_abc385                cap cost  MANU  MANU
11          funded const commit_abc385                  funded  MANU  MANU
12          funded const commit_abc385                  funded  MANU  MANU
13               future_dated_invoices            future_dated  FDIO  FDIO
14       manual_adjustment_fcst_abc385                  manual  MANU  MANU
15       manual_adjustment_fcst_abc385                  manual  MANU  MANU
16       non-tax amort cap cost_abc385                 non-tax  MANU  MANU
```

Comment: @Jim Can you please [edit] your question and put there an example what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just added a screenshot.  I have a column name in a dataframe (column_name), I want to search for the substring in the "substring to search for" column, and create another column that inputs the values from the "code" column.  I thought I could do this with a dictionary, and maybe there still is a way.  I tried your suggested and got all nans.  Thank you for your continued help!! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Jim Please, don't add screenshot, add a text (so users can copy-paste it). Also add expected results.

Comment: this worked exactly how I needed it to.  Thank you SO much for taking the time to look into this for me.  I've also never seen or used "next" in regards to lambda.  There's no way I'd have ever come up with this.  You're the best!!